AhkV1: Is possible to create a class with constructor overloads?
For example if I have a class that constructs a Timecode object, I would like to sometimes initialise a instance by  just providing a value for a single parameter (frameCount) and other times provide  more than one parameter such as frameCount and frameRate.
Here is what I tried:
obj := new timecode(2)          ;Default to using 12 frames per second
print(obj)                          ;prints ---> {"frameCount": 24, "framerate": 12}
obj := new timecode(2, 24)  ;Use the provided frame rate 
print(obj)                          ;prints ---> {"frameCount": 48, "framerate": 24}


class timecode
{
    __New(frames)
        {
            this.frameCount := frames * 12
            this.framerate := 12
        }
    __New(frames, framerate)
        {
            this.frameCount := frames * framerate
            this.framerate := framerate
        }
}

but the above just throws an error:
 ==> Duplicate declaration.
     Specifically: __New
AutoHotkey closed for the following exit code: 2

I know that V1 is as dead as latin, and V2 classes are much better now but until the library porting for V2 catches up, I will be on V1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

AutoHotkey doesn't have pattern-based matching for method overloading. But in principle, you could write one constructor that accepts all possible signatures you want.

@sytech that sounds interesting, it might be just what I need, would please share a simple example with me?

To my knowledge, there is no direct way to create a class with constructor overloads. A good indirect way that may work is the following:
; Define a struct to hold the properties of your "class"
MyClass := {}

; Define a function to act as the constructor
MyClass_New(name := "", age := 0) {
    ; Initialize a new instance of the class
    local obj := {}
    
    ; Set the properties based on the arguments passed to the constructor
    obj.name := name
    obj.age := age
    
    ; Return the instance
    return obj
}

; Usage:
obj1 := MyClass_New("John", 30)
obj2 := MyClass_New("Jane")

EDIT:
I seemed to misunderstand your question. Here is how I would get around constructor overloading:
class timecode
{
    __New(frames, framerate := 12)
    {
        if (IsObject(framerate))
        {
            ; If framerate is provided as an object, assume it's the options object
            this.frameCount := frames * (framerate.framerate ? framerate.framerate : 12)
            this.framerate := framerate.framerate ? framerate.framerate : 12
        }
        else
        {
            ; If framerate is provided as a separate parameter
            this.frameCount := frames * framerate
            this.framerate := framerate
        }
    }
}

obj := new timecode(2)          ; Default to using 12 frames per second
MsgBox % "Frame Count: " obj.frameCount ", Frame Rate: " obj.framerate

options := { framerate: 24 }
obj := new timecode(2, options) ; Use the provided frame rate 
MsgBox % "Frame Count: " obj.frameCount ", Frame Rate: " obj.framerate


Hey Steven, wellcome to SO :) , while your solution looks legible, my intention is to learn classes in AutoHotkey so as to take advantage of all of its facilities (base class inheritance, etc), is solution not essentially over stepping classes classes altogether?  I am not sure, so I would appreciate any clarifications.

You know what, though. I could be wrong. I haven't programmed with AutoHotKey in a while. You can give the code a try, but I keep trying to come up with a different solution and I can't think of another way around it. I found this (https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=50356) post where more workarounds were labeled.

I really like the use of a object to get named parameters, it should make things much more manageable, and the other shared link has more ideas too. Cheers for this!

You could implement one constructor that accepts both signatures and does the correct things depending on what is passed. You could also use variadic parameters (e.g., paramName*) to accept any arbitrary number of arguments.
class timecode {
    __New(args*) {
      if (args.Length() = 1) {
          frames := args[1]
          this.frameCount := frames * 12
          this.framerate := 12
    } else if (args.Length() = 2) {
          frames := args[1]
          framerate := args[2]
          this.frameCount := frames * framerate
          this.framerate := framerate
    } else {
          throw "Invalid number of arguments"
    }
}

You could also implement whatever logic necessary to give the same behavior of 'overloading', for example, by inspecting the type of the object(s) passed in to the constructor.
As shared in another answer you can make a signature with defaults that accomplishes this, too.

I would have never thought to use veridic parameters in a method... I guess methods can be declared just like functions, with veridic, defailt parameter values etc etc. I had no idea, also type inspecting should allow me for some rudimentary type handling, thanks for this answer!
